# set up SMTP to deliver to MySQL (not to authenticate)

Tags: mysql, smtp, email-server

We'd like to develop a system similar to Facebook, where we have an internal messaging system on the webpage, but messages are delivered to the recipients by email too, and can be replyed upon (using a special reply-to address), and those messages get into the internal messaging system too. To implement this, we need to have an SMTP server, which delivers incoming emails to a MySQL database, in which we later processes those messages. What SMTP server you suggest, and if there are anything like that, what ready-made packages?

Comment: We don't do product reccomendations here, so you might not get many suggestions but as adamo says, SMTP servers are just mail servers - they accept and deliver email. You could use any product you like (though clearly some would be better choices than others, I probably wouldn't use Exchange or Notes for this!) but what happens to the email once it has been accepted is a dev issue for you more than anything else.

Comment: MySQL is a database, so it doesn't receive emails.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is not one of what SMTP server to choose. SMTP servers accept and process incoming  and outgoing mail and then hand it over to the next server in line. If they are the last server in the line to process the message they handle it to a [message delivery agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_delivery_agent). So you need to write a special purpose message delivery agent that will accept the message from say Postfix or Sendmail and dump it to MySQL.

[dbmail](http://dbmail.org/) is a mail system that works with databases like MySQL and PostgreSQL, so it might worth a shot to have a look at how its message delivery agent handles messages.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed implementation seems overly complex: Delivering emails to a pile to be post-processed is a recipe for lag and pain (especially if you want that pile to be a SQL database).

You *probably* want your SMTP server to feed these messages to another program/script that handles them appropriately -- Look into how pipes work with your existing MTA, and see if that will work better for you.

Comment: (You can also ask another question about pipes and your current MTA if you'd like -- Make sure to tell us which MTA you're using though :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Postfix](http://www.postfix.org) is a well-known SMTP server. It is flexible and has many configuration options. You can pipe your email messages to a script and then process them in the way you like.